# Excel VBA - Strings starting with 0

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim testtext As String
testtext = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B6").Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = testtext
```

Simple copying of one cell's content into another. But I run into problems when content of B6 is `'02345` - after running the macro B7 contains `2345` and I don't want to lose the leading zero. I tried replacing `.Value` with `.Text` in second line of the code and this didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change the .NumberFormat property to "@", it will write 02345 in the cell.

```
Dim testtext As String
testtext = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B6").Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").NumberFormat = "@"

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = testtext
```

This works because the standard cell format reads a number with leading 0s as a numeric value, and therefore the leading 0s are removed.
By forcing Excel to use the text format on that particualar cell, it will not treat it as a numeric value, but just as plain text.

Comment: hehe ... you were faster .. I will delete my identical post ;)

Comment: Are you sure I was first?
Your answer was there when I submitted mine, so I guess you might have been faster or we answered simultaneously :)

Comment: doesn't matter ... at least the TO has the right answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what is the default property of `Range`, but anyway

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
  .Range("B7") = .Range("B6")
End With
```

seems to work perfectly.
If you really need the intermediate `testext` variable, I would rather define it as `Variant`.

Answer (score 2):

Try simple copying of one cell's content into another with `copy` method.

```
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B6").copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B7")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FormulaR1C1` property of a cell to insert the single quote which causes Excel to interpret it as text. This mimics what actually happens when you enter `'02345` in the `B6` originally, as you can verify by doing so with the macro recorder turned on:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").FormulaR1C1 = "'" & testtext
```